# "header already sent" error caused be detect_unicode="0"

Tags: php, character, cjk

I know that the "header already sent" error question was already answered millions of times, but I'm a little stumped with this one.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        if($_GET['logout'] == 'logout')
            $past = time() - 10; 
        setcookie('hebron_member', date("F jS - g:i a"), $past);
    } else if(isset($_GET['setcookie'])) {
        if($_GET['setcookie'] == '1'){
            $month = 2592000 + time();
            setcookie('hebron_member', $_GET['id'], $month);
        }
    }
?>
```

That is at the top of my index page. When I transferred all my files to the webserver via Filezilla, the Korean characters were showing up as question marks. I did some research and saw that I could change the php.ini file to include `detect_unicode="0"`, which fixed the problem, but since I've added that line, I get a "Cannot send session cache limiter" error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure to save your files in UTF-8 without BOM

you can do it by using Notepad++ and save it as UTF-8 encoding without BOM =)

Comment: I had already done that. Everything was working fine when viewing it on my own computer using XAMPP. And there were no errors on the webserver regarding the header() until I added the detect_unicode="0" line.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I just looked at your post more carefully and checked to look for a "without BOM" option. That fixed the problem! Can you explain a little bit what exactly the BOM does?

Comment: I think transferring data through FTP makes the problem as it pass the file and doesn't preserve the UTF-8 encoding(as it was my problem before)... is there any option that you can change the files encoding of your files on your web server?

Comment: ok the BOM is what the PHP non-english developers "Headache"... well I experienced the BOM problem when I was developing a Japanese website. its here for you to read about what the heck BOM does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0):

A very common and annoying problem is having a whitespace or line before the PHP opening tag

Comment: Checked, double checked, and triple checked :(